# How to use Google Tag Manager for iOS (swift) with GCP Recommendations AI?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager, google-cloud-recommendation

We are planning to make a recommendations engine for the features in the app and we were thinking about using GCP Recommendations AI. Then, we ran into some unclear areas due to lack of examples.

Can we use Google Tag Manager for iOS (with Firebase Analytics) to send real-time event data to GCP Recommendations AI? Could you please provide some docs/examples/articles that explains how (We are using Swift to code the app)? It is possible for web sites, according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/record-events#gtm).

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Unless it's not a native app.

If it is a web-app, then sure you can use the power of JS to send whatever you need to any endpoint. We use Segment for real time personalization, but even that requires quite a lot of involvement from the app teams. And no, GTM is not helpful for native apps.

If you already have custom analytics tracking implemented in your app, then there's a high chance that the devs used a wrapper around the firebase/gtm sdk to send events in a more comfortable way or add adequate logging. In that wrapper then, the devs could implement the event streaming to your GCP recommendations AI in case it has the capability to store data.

If it does not, you can still set up a neat app engine (or a differnet endpoint) and stream data to it. The app engine would allow you to tweak, sanitize and debug the data, after which you can stream them to something like Big Query, which your Recommendation AI would likely to be happy to work with.

I'm talking about app engine and big query because there's a nice repo I've used a few years ago... Here: https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/ga-bq-stream

This repo is attempting to use front-end GTM to stream events, but you won't be able to use it (unless you're dealing with a web app). So instead, you stream them in a very similar way from your analytics wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply BNazaruk. There is a method to real time event tracking of an iOS application using Google Tag Manager in firebase. Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaXVnvEzzTc But I'm seeking a way to combined both Recommendation AI and Google Tag Manager with iOS application.  Is there a custom way to ingest data from iOS mobile application to Recommendation AI using Google Tag Manager?

Comment: GA/FB don't offer real time data aggregation. That data is not aggregated. You can try sending your real time data from GTM using function calls or maybe custom image tags. You'd likely have to go the function route. That would require creating a data send function in the iOS codebase to be available for GTM to call. But that would effectively result in routing real-time data to your endpoint.